# Flutter - How to pass profile picture and name data to drawer from login screen

Tags: android, authentication, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and facing issue in passing data of profile picture and name from login screen to main screen drawer.please help.Thanks in advance.

```
var graphResponse = await http.get(           'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.height(200)&access_token=${facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token}');

var profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);

  onLoginStatusChanged(true, profileData: profile);
```

i can get profile image through

```
 profileData['picture']['data']['url']
```

and name using

```
profileData['name']
```

I want to show this image and profile picture in drawer in another screen named `main.dart`
[image: image of main screen shown here]

Comment: To share data between multiple screens one way to use provider ( https://pub.dev/packages/provider ) for state management. Using provider you can update data of one screen from another screen without passing it. I don't have an example code right now but may be you can solve your problem using it.

Comment: Thank you @Parth Patel for your response. let me try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use navigator to pass data to second drawer  screen with some data in constructor of drawer screen

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DrawerScreen(profiledata:ProfileData)),
```

);

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways.

See:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-ways-to-pass-to-and-share-data-with-widgets-pages-f8988534bd5b

Comment: hello @Elialber Lopes, the drawer is not in the same screen so i need to pass that profile data . i think your answer is for displaying data in same screen.Thank you.

Comment: Ok.. You can pass a parameter.. I will edit the answer